# How to submit an App that requires a login

Tags: ios, app-store

I am submitting an app that integrates with another system. In order to use the app you need to have a system login which Apple would not have.

What are the guidelines for sumbmitting an app of this nature? I assume there could be some issues if the only screen that the Apple test team can see is the login screen.

Thanks,

Joe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created a couple of apps similar to this.  We provided Apple with more or less dummy accounts that could get past the login screen, and view the basic functionality of the app, but didn't release any secret information we didn't want out

Answer (score 2):

You should provide a test account for Apple reviewers and specify the login credentials when submitting the app.